# Proper way to store mobile numbers

Tags: android

I am completely new to android. I am trying to build an app, where the user can save few mobile numbers.(In setting activity of the app)

And I have a button in the main activity on clicking it i need to send a pre defined message to the contact numbers which was already saved by the user.

So should I write down the numbers entered in a file internally or is there any other concept that will save the data entered by the user and use it for the apps further use

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/ ... section storage or something similar ... but i would recomend to start from the begining

Comment: use sharedpreferences if the number of numbers are really few

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePrefrence or Sqlite Database to save value, So that you can retrieve it later whenever required Tutorials to use are below:

SharePrefrences:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Database:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

[SqliteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) suits best for this case. You can store all the numbers in the sqlite database and there are number of [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) for knowing how to use it.